# Parsing function / method content using Reflection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

My unit testing frameworks consists of TestFixtures, TestMethods and Actions. Action is additional smaller container inside TestMethod, Actions comes from internal Dll written in our company. Actions are used inside methods like that:

```
[Test]
void TestMethod1()
{
    Run(new Sleep { Seconds = 10 } );
}
```

I have to write an application, which collect all the information about fixtures, tests and actions from DLL. I have found how to enumerate test fixtures and test methods by reflection using type / method attributes.

But I have no idea how enumerate actions inside test methods.

Could you please help? Is it possible to do using reflection at all?

**UPDATED:**
See the accepted answer. Really cool library. Also you can look here ( [WPF: Binding TreeView in MVVM way step by step tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789563/wpf-binding-treeview-in-mvvm-way-step-by-step-tutorial) ), if you are interested in how I created entity model for fixtures, tests and actions, and binded in MVVM way to TreeView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Alexei Levenkov! Finally I have found a solution using your tip. Sharing. The only thing you should do -> download and reference Mono.Reflection.dll from https://github.com/jbevain/mono.reflection.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using MINT;
using MbUnit.Framework;
using Mono.Reflection;

namespace TestDll
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string DllPath = @"d:\SprinterAutomation\Actions.Tests\bin\x86\Debug\Actions.Tests.dll";
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(DllPath);

            // enumerating Fixtures
            foreach (Type fixture in assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestFixtureAttribute), false).Length > 0)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fixture.Name);
                // enumerating Test Methods
                foreach (var testMethod in fixture.GetMethods().Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), false).Length > 0))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + testMethod.Name);
                    // filtering Actions
                    var instructions = testMethod.GetInstructions().Where(
                        i => i.OpCode.Name.Equals("newobj") && ((ConstructorInfo)i.Operand).DeclaringType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseAction)));

                    // enumerating Actions!
                    foreach (Instruction action in instructions)
                    {
                        var constructroInfo = action.Operand as ConstructorInfo;
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + constructroInfo.DeclaringType.Name);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes to extent.

Reflection will give you method body, than you need to disassemble the IL to read method body and obtain any information you want.

```
var bytes = mi.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
```

One of possible tools to disassembe is [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil)

Check out [Traverse a c# method and anazlye the method body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413779/traverse-a-c-sharp-method-and-anazlye-the-method-body) for more links.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using reflection, why don't you roll out your own method that will log all Action executions.

```
void ExecuteAction(Action action)
{
   //Log TestFixture, TestMethod, Action

   //Execute actual action
}

[Test]
void TestMethod1()
{
    ExecuteAction(Run(new Sleep { Seconds = 10 } ));
}
```

ExecuteAction method can be in a base or helper class

Comment: Thanks for answer. You meant functions like: Before each action, after each action, etc.? But it doesn't fit. I have ability to log which actions are running while running.  But I have to collect all the information from the DLL, not during the run in runtime.