# TreeViewItem Binding from code

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

i know that it doesnt overly follow the MVVM but i didnt have much of a choice.
Im building a WMI browser (As such)

the thing lists all the namespaces, the user then clicks the namespace they want and then lists all the classes in a treeview box.

the user then clicks on the treeview box and Methods/Instances/Properties are loaded underneath the treeview item clicked.

Everything is working i get the treeview items with propeties/methods and so forth.
they are even expanded however there are just blank items there.
Anyone have any idea how to bind Ovbservablecollections to a treeview item list?

Here is the code.

My View:

```
public void TreeView_BaseClasses_Event_SelectionChanged(Object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
   if (this.IsLoaded)
   {
      if (((TreeView)sender).Name == "TreeView_BaseClasses")
      {
         TreeView TheTreeView = e.OriginalSource as TreeView;

         TreeViewItem SelectionChanged = ((TreeView)sender).ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(TheTreeView.Items.IndexOf(TheTreeView.SelectedItem)) as TreeViewItem;
         SelectionChanged.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem()
         {
             Header = "Properties",
             ItemsSource = "BaseClassesData",
             DisplayMemberPath = "ClassProperties"
         }
         );
         SelectionChanged.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem()
         {
             Header = "Methods",
             ItemsSource = "BaseClassesData",
             DisplayMemberPath = "ClassMethods"
         }
         );
         SelectionChanged.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem()
         {
             Header = "Instances",
             ItemsSource = "BaseClassesData",
             DisplayMemberPath = "ClassInstances"
         }
         );
         SelectionChanged.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem()
         {
             Header = "Sub Classes",
             ItemsSource = "BaseClassesData",
             DisplayMemberPath = "ClassSubClasses"
         }
         );
         ThisViewModel.SelectedItem = SelectionChanged;
         ThisViewModel.Children();
         SelectionChanged.ExpandSubtree();
         SelectionChanged.IsSelected = true;
         e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

My View Model

```
public void Children()
{
   base.GetClassData(SelectedItem.Header.ToString());
}
```

My Model

```
 public void GetClassData(string ClassName)
 {
     ManagementClass EnumClasses = new ManagementClass(ClassName);
     ClassData NewClass = new ClassData();
     try
     {
        foreach (ManagementObject objClass in EnumClasses.GetSubclasses())
        {
            NewClass.ClassSubClasses.Add(objClass.ClassPath.ClassName);
        }
        foreach (ManagementObject objInstance in EnumClasses.GetInstances())
        {
            NewClass.ClassInstances.Add(objInstance.ToString());
        }
        foreach (PropertyData Prop in EnumClasses.Properties)
        {
            NewClass.ClassProperties.Add(Prop.Name);
        }
        foreach (MethodData meth in EnumClasses.Methods)
        {
            NewClass.ClassMethods.Add(meth.Name);
        }
        NewClass.ClassEnumeration();
     }
     catch {

     }
     finally
     {
         BaseClassesData.Add(NewClass);
     }
}
public class ClassData
{
    public String ClassName { get; set; }
    public String ClassPath { get; set; }
    public ManagementScope ClassScope { get; set; }
    public ISite ClassSite { get; set; }
    public String ClassNamespace { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<String> ClassInstances { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<String> ClassProperties { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<String> ClassSubClasses { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<String> ClassMethods { get; set; }
    public ClassData()
    {
        ClassInstances = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        ClassProperties = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        ClassSubClasses = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        ClassMethods = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
    public void ClassEnumeration()
    {
        if (ClassName != null)
        {
           ClassPath = new ManagementClass(ClassName).ClassPath.Path;
           ClassScope = new ManagementClass(ClassName).Scope;
           ClassSite = new ManagementClass(ClassName).Site;
           ClassNamespace = new ManagementClass(ClassName).ClassPath.NamespacePath;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: i found that i can use ItemsSource = ThisViewModel.ViewBaseClassesData[0].ClassProperties, but there has to be a better way. this is my view accessing my view model which is bad

Comment: "Everything is working i get the treeview items with propeties/methods and so forth. they are even expanded however there are just blank items there." - TreeView is just displaying data you have. Blank TreeViewItems mean you have empty data items in your collection.

Comment: ive checked the data. and its valid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right this is not following MVVM and the problem is in how you are setting ItemSource -

```
ItemsSource = "BaseClassesData",
```

I think you might have to first specify TreeNode's DataContext and then create a binding to specify ItemSource (instead of just specifying `ItemsSource = "BaseClassesData`")
Or directly specify ItemSource as you mentioned in your comment.

Both the above cses will require you to access your ViewModel in View, and there is nothing wrong in `View accessing ViewModel`; in MVVM view always depends on ViewModel and always knows about it and uses it ( Indirectly through Bindings and Directly in code).

Finally, In case this is not just a temp. project and needs to be maintained/enhanced in future I would suggest you to implement proper MVVM; you will come across a lot of requirements like selection, expansion, dynamic loading, search etc., and doing all this in code will be very cumbersome and unmaintainable.

Please have a look at following article to do so -

[Simplifying the WPF TreeView by Using the ViewModel Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode)

Also have a look at following SO question having code for doing something very similar using MVVM -

[WPF: Binding TreeView in MVVM way step by step tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789563/wpf-binding-treeview-in-mvvm-way-step-by-step-tutorial)

Comment: as i said, i know it doesnt follow the MVVM pattern. however my model is getting all the data no problems. and i was doing this just for testing. my issue is now how do i get my data to display. i cannot find any tutorials on binding a class to multiple treeview layers where the source is dynamic. it looks like i might have to have my entire treeview in a observable collection, which i do not want to do as the class data is used elsewhere.