# How to return string content through Reflection

Tags: c#

I have this `static` generic method under the  `static` `class` `Program`. I am trying to retrieve the `string` content through reflection.

```
public static string DisplaySomeStuff<T>(T toDisplay) where T : class
{
    return string.Format("Here it is: {0}", toDisplay);
}
```

Comment: What string you are trying to retrieve? Please show code that you have problem with... (see [MCVE] for guidance)

Comment: I want to retrieve the string inside the body of the above method.

Comment: `"Here it is: {0}"` - that string? Would be so much easier if you'd [edit] post with code you'd tried and output you expect... (And I'd not need to waste my vote so I could close it as duplicate of something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679240/parsing-function-method-content-using-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

With C# 6.0, you can use the `nameof` operator:

```cs
nameof(T)
```