# EF Core Mapping Entities to Models

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, extension-methods, sql-generation

I'm trying to efficiently map entities on to models.

My entities are:

```
public class ParentEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    public ChildEntity Child { get; set; }
}

public class ChildEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and my models are:

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ChildModel Child { get; set; }
}

public class ChildModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

(In practice, there would be differences between these classes, but not here for simplification.)

I've written an extension method to do the mapping:

```
public static IQueryable<ParentModel> ToParentModel (this IQueryable<ParentEntity> parentEntities)
{
    return parentEntities.Select(p => new ParentModel
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        Name = p.Name,
        Child = new ChildModel { Id = p.Child.Id, Name = p.Child.Name.ToLower()}
    });
}
```

The `ToLower()` is there to highlight the problem.

I can run this with:

```
var parents = _context.Set<ParentEntity>().ToParentModel().ToArray();
```

The generated SQL is:

```
 SELECT "p"."Id", "p"."Name", "c"."Id", lower("c"."Name") AS "Name"
 FROM "Parents" AS "p"
 LEFT JOIN "Children" AS "c" ON "p"."ChildId" = "c"."Id"
```

i.e. the lowercase processing is done in the database.

All good so far, except that the separation of concerns is not good. The code to initialize a `ChildModel` is in the same place as the code to initialize a `ParentModel`.

I try using a constructor in `ChildModel`:

```
public ChildModel(ChildEntity ent)
{
    Id = ent.Id;
    Name = ent.Name.ToLower();
}
```

and in the extension method:

```
return parentEntities.Select(p => new ParentModel
{
    Id = p.Id,
    Name = p.Name,
    Child = new ChildModel (p.Child)
});
```

This works, but the generated SQL does not do contains a `lower`. The conversion to lowercase is done in the program.

Is there a way I can have by cake and eat it?

Can I still have my C# code converted to SQL, but still structure my C# code in a modular way?

Comment: Is using AutoMapper with the `ProjectTo()` extension method an option? Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I think AutoMapper could work. But what I want to know is how AutoMapper does it.

Answer (score 2):

EF Core's `IQueryable` implementations utilize [ExpressionTrees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/) to defer as much work to the database as possible.

### Context

From Microsoft:

> Expression trees represent code in a tree-like data structure, where each node is an expression, for example, a method call or a binary operation such as 'x < y'

When you are using `Select` with model `setters`:

```
return parentEntities.Select(p => new ParentModel
{
    Id = p.Id,
    Name = p.Name,
    Child = new ChildModel { Id = p.Child.Id, Name = p.Child.Name.ToLower()}
});
```

This translates to a tree of expressions looking something like:

```
Expression-> Func<Parent, ParentModdel>
-- BinaryExpression.Assign-> ParentModel.Id->setter, Parent.Id->getter
-- BinaryExpression.Assign-> ParentModel.Name->setter, Parent.Name->getter
-- BinaryExpression.Assign-> ParentModel.Child->setter, Expression->Func<Parent, ChildModel>

// Expression->Func<Parent, ChildModel> looks something like:
BinaryExpression.Assign-> ChildModel.Id->setter, Parent.Child.Id->getter
BinaryExpression.Assign-> ChildModel.Name->setter, Parent.Child.Name->getter
```

I'm using pseudo-code to simplify the illustration of the tree-like structure, because ExpressionTree syntax is very verbose and can be quite confusing and frankly is outside the scope of the question at hand. See [Assign expression here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.assign?view=net-7.0).

When you are using the constructor syntax:

```
Child = new ChildModel (p.Child)
```

it's contents cannot be efficiently inferred. Constructors are effectively treated as Methods, meaning that you can describe their arguments, return type and invocation as expressions, but not it's contents. Hence EF has no option, but to create a simple expression tree that fetches the Parent object from the SQL and then execute the `ChildModel` constructor in memory, thus invoking the string.ToLower() operation.

*Note: it is possible to [read the method contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679240/parsing-function-method-content-using-reflection), but that involves decompiling the IL, which is far to intensive and slow to be part of database queries. This is what VS does when you inspect a method from a referenced library*

### Answer

**AutoMapper** runs it's heavy duty Reflection on program startup to generate object maps, which as you might guess, represent `ExpressionTree`s. By default it uses naming conventions i.e. it would map `Id` -> `Id` and `ChildId` -> `ChildId` or `Child.Id`. It also exposes API to define your own custom mappings for more complex scenarios.